# How to reference yData from another series in each category of a highcharts column chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a column chart, which displays two series, with data for a number of years.

Each year has a column for each of the two series.

I want to create a data label for these columns that shows the percentage of the total sum of the value of the two columns (sum of yData) for each year. To do this I need to reference both the current y value and the sum of the two y values in a given category (year).

I've tried something like this:

```
dataLabels:{
    enabled:true,
    formatter:function(e) {
        var mychart = $('#e_74').highcharts();
        var sum = parseInt(mychart .series[1].yData, 10) + parseInt(mychart .series[0].yData, 10);
        var pcnt = (this.y / sum * 100);
        return Highcharts.numberFormat(pcnt) + '%';                     
    }
}
```

**The Problem:**

This works for the first year / category, because the sum of the yData is always the sum of the first element of the two series - so it is correct in the first year. However subsequent years still reference the total of the sum of these first two elements - making subsequent data labels inaccurate.

How can I reference the current sum of the yData for each individual category?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RG8YT/12/) of my work in progress

And here is a copy of the complete code I'm trying to implement for this graph

```
$(function () {         
     $('#e_74').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        credits: {
        enabled: false
        },
        noData: {
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: '20px'
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Title',
        },
        navigation: {
            buttonOptions:
            {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
              categories: [2013, 2014]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Number '
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:,.0f} </b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0,
                borderWidth: 0
                },
            series: {
             dataLabels:{
                    enabled:true,
                    formatter:function(e) {
                        var mychart = $('#e_74').highcharts();    
                        var sum = parseInt(mychart.series[1].yData[1], 10) + parseInt(mychart.series[0].yData[1], 10);
                        var pcnt = (this.y /  sum * 100);
                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(pcnt) + '%';
                    }
                }
                }
            },
            series: [{showInLegend: true, name: 'With trained HW', data: [94426, 147615]}, {showInLegend: true, name: 'Without trained HW', data: [16863, 29198]}]
        });
    });
```

Comment: updated answer with more efficient example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the x index in order to reference the right category.

If you do this with a loop, you can make it dynamic so that it works with any number of series:

```
formatter:function() {
  var i = this.point.index;
  var sum = 0;
  $.each(this.series.chart.series, function() {
    sum += this.yData[i];
  })
  var pcnt = (this.y /  sum * 100);
  return Highcharts.numberFormat(pcnt) + '%';
}
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/89uny567/

Example with additional series:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/89uny567/1/

OTOH, this redundantly calculates totals, which could be a problem if you have a lot of data points.

It might be worthwhile to calculate the relevant values before building the chart, and sending the appropriate percent value along with each data point as an optional variable to reference from the data label instead.

**EDIT -------------------**

Example that pre-processes the data and uses a 'totals' array to calculate the percentage for each bar, thereby avoiding the repeated calculation of the same totals for each bar:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/89uny567/2/